# How to get months between 2 dates with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

What I want to get is the date from the last record of the table, and how many months have passes since that date and today.

Example of the query I want to create:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(created_at),  
    extract(year from age(NOW(), MAX(created))) * 12 + extract(month from age(NOW(), MAX(created))) AS months_beween 
FROM 
    packages
WHERE 
    userId = theUserId
GROUP BY 
    userId;
```

Desired result:

```
max                           | months_between
-----------------------------------------------
2023-10-31 17:39:26.432552+00 |        3
```

How can I get the calculation of the months with Entity Framework?

Comment: What RDBMS are you targeting? Your query looks like a mix of Postgres and T-SQL.

Comment: @Dai PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the calculation of the months with Entity Framework, you can use the DbFunctions class, which provides common date and time operations. For example, you can write something like this:

```
var result = from p in db.Packages
             where p.userId == theUserId
             group p by p.userId into g
             select new {
                 MaxDate = g.Max(p => p.created_at),
                 MonthsBetween = DbFunctions.DiffMonths(g.Max(p => p.created_at), DateTime.Now)
             };
```